# Solution of quadratic optimization with linear constraints

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, constraints

Hi， I want to solve a quadratic optimization problem defined as

$\min \|\bf{a^T}\bf{x}\|^2_2$

$s.t. \|\bf{x}\|_1=1$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x_i\ge0,\ i=0,1,...,n-1$

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \bf{b}^T\bf{x}-C\le0$

where $\bf{x},\bf{a},\bf{b}\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times1}$ and their entries are positive. $C$ is a constant value with $C>0$.

I know it is easy but I can't solve it myself. Giving me some references is OK.

I found this problem is similar to Markowitz portfolio theory (right?), but I don't know anything about finance. Thanks!

Comment: are you expected to solve it analytically?  or is this a specific problem with numerical values?

Comment: analytically, thanks

Comment: probably Lagrange multipliers then

Comment: I would say, just throw this into your favorite QP solver. Analytic solutions are generally not available.

Comment: I found a solution in [link](https://www.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/408/fin-proj/mark1.pdf). It is clear.